# Create and sell sub-activities in-app

Tags: android

I am developing a game that is a collector of mini-games.

Every minigame is an activity, that is extended from a common GameActivity class.

My idea is to let the user buy more games in-app. What is the best practice for doing it?

The easiest way is of course to create two versions of the game, with a different number of sub-activities, but what if I want users to buy only certain subactivities, and not others?

My first idea was to create only one free app, with ALL the sub-activities, but many of them blocked. Then, sell single small apps that don't cointain any game, but instead generate a file that is checked by the main app and unblocks the relative sub-activities.
The problem of this solution is that, anyway, I always have to force users that want only the limited free version, to download also sub-activities that they won't ever use.

This is a good solution, or is there something better?

Thank you.

Comment: You should check out http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html - in app purchases would allow you to unlock activities without having to download additional apps

Comment: Thanks but my question was if there exists a different method that allows people to download only new activities that integrate my application.